# Error id null java al intentar guardar un registro en la bd, el Id está configurado para generarse automáticamente

Tags: java, base-de-datos, error404

Al intentar guardar un registro en la bd arroja este error  ERROR: null value in column "id_parametrizacion" violates not-null constraint, pero el id está diseñado para generarse automáticamente. Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando, ya que he consultado y no debería arrojar error porque el id está generado automáticamente.

Si alguien sabe por qué está ocurriendo eso, le agradecería que me pueda ayudar solucionandolo, ya que no he podido encontrar solución alguna

Adjunto el código de las clases involucradas

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "parametrizacion_impuesto", schema = "impuestos_municipales")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "ParametrizacionImpuesto.findByVigencia", query = "SELECT new co.com.moviliza.impuestosmunicipales.dto.ParametrizacionImpuestosDTO(p.idParametrizacion,ti.nombreImpuesto,p.activo) FROM ParametrizacionImpuesto p JOIN p.idTipoImpuesto ti WHERE p.idTipoVigencia.idTipoVigencia = :vigencia   AND   p.idAutoridadTransito.idAutoridadTransito = :idAutoridadTransito"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "ParametrizacionImpuesto.findById", query = "SELECT new co.com.moviliza.impuestosmunicipales.dto.ParametrizacionImpuestosDTO(p.idParametrizacion,ti.idTipoImpuesto,ti.nombreImpuesto,p.activo,tc.idTipoCobro,tc.nombreCobro,COALESCE(tr.idTipoRedondeo, NULL), COALESCE(tr.nombreRedondeo, NULL),p.aplicaCobroInteres,tv.valorSmlv,tv.vigencia) FROM ParametrizacionImpuesto p JOIN p.idTipoImpuesto ti JOIN p.idTipoCobro tc LEFT JOIN p.idTipoRedondeo tr JOIN p.idTipoVigencia tv WHERE p.idParametrizacion = :idParametrizacion  ORDER BY p.idParametrizacion ASC") })
public class ParametrizacionImpuesto implements Serializable {

    /** La constante serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** Atributo id parametrizacion. */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_parametrizacion")
    private int idParametrizacion;

    /** Atributo id autoridad de transito */
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_autoridad_transito", referencedColumnName = "id_autoridad_transito")
    @ManyToOne
    private AutoridadTransito idAutoridadTransito;

    /** Atributo id tipo impuesto */
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_impuesto", referencedColumnName = "id_tipo_impuesto")
    @ManyToOne
    private TipoImpuesto idTipoImpuesto;

    /** Atributo id tipo vigencia */
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_vigencia", referencedColumnName = "id_tipo_vigencia")
    @ManyToOne
    private TipoVigencia idTipoVigencia;

    /** Atributo id tipo redondeo */
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_redondeo", referencedColumnName = "id_tipo_redondeo")
    @ManyToOne
    private TipoRedondeo idTipoRedondeo;

    /** Atributo id tipo cobro */
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_cobro", referencedColumnName = "id_tipo_cobro")
    @ManyToOne
    private TipoCobro idTipoCobro;

    /** Atributo aplica cobro interes */
    @Column(name = "aplica_cobro_interes")
    private boolean aplicaCobroInteres;

    /** Atributo activo */
    @Column(name = "activo")
    private boolean activo;
}
```

```
 public mensaje guardarParametrizacion(int idTipoVigencia, int idTipoImpuesto, int idTipoCobro,
            int idTipoRedondeo, boolean aplicaCobro) {
        mensae salida= new mensaje();
        salida.setCodigoRespuesta(ConstantesComunes.CodigoRespuesta.Exitoso.name());

        try {
            ParametrizacionImpuesto parametrizacionNueva = new ParametrizacionImpuesto();

            TipoVigencia tipoVigencia = tipoVigenciaDAO.find(idTipoVigencia);
            parametrizacionNueva.setIdTipoVigencia(tipoVigencia);

            TipoImpuesto tipoImpuesto = tipoImpuestoDAO.find(idTipoImpuesto);
            parametrizacionNueva.setIdTipoImpuesto(tipoImpuesto);

            TipoCobro tipoCobro = tipoCobroDAO.findTipoCobro(idTipoCobro);
            parametrizacionNueva.setIdTipoCobro(tipoCobro);

            if (idTipoRedondeo != 0) {
                TipoRedondeo tipoRedondeoNuevo = tipoRedondeoDAO.findTipoRedondeo(idTipoRedondeo);
                parametrizacionNueva.setIdTipoRedondeo(tipoRedondeoNuevo);
            } else {
                parametrizacionNueva.setIdTipoRedondeo(null);
            }

            AutoridadTransito autoridadTransito = autoridadTransitoDAO.find(1);
            parametrizacionNueva.setIdAutoridadTransito(autoridadTransito);

            parametrizacionNueva.setAplicaCobroInteres(aplicaCobro);
            parametrizacionNueva.setActivo(true);
            parametrizacionImpuestoDAO.insert(parametrizacionNueva);

            salida.setMensajeRespuesta("La información ha sido guardada satisfactoriamente");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            salida.setCodigoRespuesta(ConstantesComunes.CodigoRespuesta.Fallido.name());
            salida.setMensajeRespuesta(
                    "No se pudo guardar la Parametrización. Comuniquese con el administrador del sistema.");
        }

        return salida;

    }
```

```
 public void insert(ParametrizacionImpuesto parametrizacionImpuestoNueva) {
        entityManager.persist(parametrizacion`introducir el código aquí`ImpuestoNueva);
    }
```

Comment: Hola Santiago, no estaría demás indicarnos el motor de base de datos que utilizas, quizás falta alguna configuración en tu base de datos para que te genere una llave al momento de insertar  un registro.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Santiago intenta cambiando     `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` por la siguiente sentencia, la cual usa el generador global.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Igual revisa la documentación oficial :
[Generated Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html)